# What is the phrasal verb that has similar meaning to 'unfriend'?

Tags: word-request, phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

So I kind of remembered this phrasal verb **cut  + somebody + off**, note that I'm not sure about the adverb particle, it's possibly either **off** or **out** or else I couldn't remember. Anyway I saw this when I was playing a novel game (I don't remember the name of the game).

> The story is about a lonely boy who thinks he's being hated by his
> friend and turns to be a bad boy. He complains about the way his
> friends treat him as if he is **cut off/out** by them. However, his
> friends tell him that he is the one who *cut off/out* them first.

Anyway, that's the best I could remember about the story. One of the characters use the the prasal verb that's started by a verb **cut**. Can you tell me which phrasal verb I'm looking for? I suppose, it has similar meaning to unfriend. Like when someone cuts the friendship or something.

Comment: Synonym [**ostracise**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ostracize)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm kind of familiar with this one. Is it like when I join in a club with people and they like exclude me? Eh? Thanks, but I need the phrasal verb.

Comment: Why do you "need" a phrasal verb? You could say your friends ***threw** you **out*** or ***shut** you **out***, or you could use a longer idiom, such as they ***sent** you **to Coventry***. But I don't really understand your context. How come your boy has friends, if nobody likes him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "cut [someone] off" could be understood as refusing to have any further contact with them. (It has other unrelated meanings too.)

To "cut [someone] out" could be understood as excluding them from a social group, by not inviting them to future group events. (It also has other unrelated meanings.)

Either of these phrases might be used in the context of terminating a friendship, so based on the information you've provided here, it's difficult or impossible to know what you're remembering.